# ¿Es posible dibujar más de una imagen dentro de la banda TITULO de un reporte Jaspersoft?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estoy intentando imprimir una hoja A4 dividido en tres partes, cada una de esas partes tiene como elemento un logo en el titulo que debe ser compilador e impreso en la hoja entera, de la siguiente manera;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las imagenes tiene la propiedad blank cuando surge algún error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente la primer imagen consigue mostrar el logo pero las demás que tienen la misma configuración no muestran, cuando paso la propiedad On Error Type a "ERROR" lanza la siguiente linea;

```
sep 23, 2021 4:15:09 PM net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerPanel paintPage
GRAVE: Page paint error.
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:196)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplatePrintImage.accept(JRTemplatePrintImage.java:452)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:266)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:188)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:238)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplatePrintFrame.accept(JRTemplatePrintFrame.java:104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:266)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:214)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportPage(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:350)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReportToGraphics2D(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:316)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReport(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:231)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerPanel.paintPage(JRViewerPanel.java:521)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerPanel$PageRenderer.paintComponent(JRViewerPanel.java:611)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5217)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1042)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1975)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3904)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:842)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.imprimir(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:456)
    at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.guardar(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:523)
    at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.actionPerformed(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:621)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at iOS.vista.ventanas.principales.VentanaPrincipal.abrirTransaccionPedido(VentanaPrincipal.java:442)
    at iOS.vista.ventanas.principales.VentanaPrincipal.access$8(VentanaPrincipal.java:437)
    at iOS.vista.ventanas.principales.VentanaPrincipal$28.actionPerformed(VentanaPrincipal.java:391)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:70)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes(JRImageLoader.java:161)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.WrappingImageDataToGraphics2DRenderer.getImage(WrappingImageDataToGraphics2DRenderer.java:76)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.WrappingImageDataToGraphics2DRenderer.render(WrappingImageDataToGraphics2DRenderer.java:102)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.ImageDrawer$InternalImageDrawer.drawFillFrame(ImageDrawer.java:279)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.ImageDrawer$InternalImageDrawer.draw(ImageDrawer.java:208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.ImageDrawer.draw(ImageDrawer.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:187)
    ... 165 more
```

Pueden confirmar si mi configuración esta correcta o debo hacer de otra manera?

CODIGO DEL JRXML:

```
<band height="102" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="255" height="56" uuid="a9a13458-6932-4099-8329-c877c5fc506a"/>
            <rectangle radius="5">
                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="255" height="56" uuid="af0215d2-0ef8-4b1c-94b8-f61f87eb3940"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" onErrorType="Blank">
                <reportElement x="130" y="7" width="113" height="42" uuid="db5d4b7a-c3fa-43d8-98a8-a5fea5470753"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="7" width="110" height="17" uuid="8bd067da-ff0b-42aa-b05b-53ec598b9b73">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PEDIDO "+$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="d MMM, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="10" y="31" width="100" height="17" uuid="af636a19-8ce6-4909-ab4d-9e061fdfc9a2"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fechaRegistro}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="64" width="255" height="38" uuid="d53b1f26-655e-4851-8fc9-f6822df8d2e5"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="255" height="17" uuid="5baa92e5-c790-4eff-bf6c-3c526b7f8096">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cliente "+$F{cliente.nombreCompleto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="21" width="255" height="17" uuid="cf247af5-d513-4e33-a73d-12382eb558ed">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Contacto "+$F{cliente.contacto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="274" y="0" width="255" height="56" uuid="de870e04-7223-4fbd-bfde-b7753be55e9a"/>
            <rectangle radius="5">
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="255" height="56" uuid="2d054806-9ff7-48e4-9651-05e8bd6bdd94"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="130" y="7" width="113" height="42" uuid="24173c24-a631-424f-91bf-3821ca36018a"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="7" width="110" height="17" uuid="e3b2382d-df64-498f-9a60-308d0f71c8f2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PEDIDO "+$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="d MMM, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="10" y="31" width="100" height="17" uuid="1bc2836c-a8af-47a1-9885-dff20d48ee53"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fechaRegistro}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="274" y="64" width="255" height="38" uuid="9f48f23a-3635-4725-8276-098ae441cacd"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="255" height="17" uuid="9398fed7-ce67-479f-bfc3-a8d58365bc6f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cliente "+$F{cliente.nombreCompleto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="21" width="255" height="17" uuid="decf4940-9dc8-4950-be41-1316aa4fa096">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Contacto "+$F{cliente.contacto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="547" y="0" width="255" height="56" uuid="b4ba963b-7c65-40a7-9d12-83baeb19bdd6"/>
            <rectangle radius="5">
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="-1" y="0" width="255" height="56" uuid="72d94dd4-6735-4e94-bd43-adb5cbb5c900"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="9" y="7" width="110" height="17" uuid="f99adbe5-9b1f-443c-ba03-331c9c2ac4b4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PEDIDO "+$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="d MMM, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="9" y="31" width="100" height="17" uuid="0b0ad32d-2d5c-498e-a30d-5e75577fddda"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fechaRegistro}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" isLazy="true" onErrorType="Blank" evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement x="130" y="7" width="113" height="42" uuid="1dabc4ab-2a3e-4b49-812a-c23ea4ece252"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="547" y="64" width="255" height="38" uuid="9aff19e3-49f9-410e-a969-75892e597761"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="0" width="255" height="17" uuid="b1e740de-6696-4e8a-b8d4-5d58cdc8d55f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cliente "+$F{cliente.nombreCompleto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="21" width="255" height="17" uuid="b8622a2d-4cf8-42d8-90cc-5e9378b36fae">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Contacto "+$F{cliente.contacto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
```

Comment: Incluye a la pregunta el jrxml, o por lo menos la parte correspondiente a la imagen.

Comment: @Sal listo, el código referente a la banda del título donde se encuentran las imágenes

Comment: ¿`$P{logo}` es una URL? Prueba con Evaluation Time: Now y Using Cache = true.